# How would I answer the following questions on modular congruence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, induction

"Find an integer $x$ which satisfies the congruence. Justify each answer.

a) $32x ≡ 8 \mod 13$

b) $39x ≡ 65 \mod 169$

c) $x^2 − 7x ≡ 10 \mod 11$

I understand what the question is asking but I am not sure how I would manipulate it in such a way as to find $x$. Am I supposed to use the Euclidean algorithm to solve for $x$ ? If so, how?

Any input would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$ $32x - 8 = 13k \implies 32x = 13k+8 \implies 13k = 8(4x-1)\implies 13 \mid (4x-1)\implies 4x-1 = 13n\implies x = \dfrac{13n+1}{4}= 3n +\dfrac{n+1}{4}\implies n+1 = 4p\implies n = 4p-1\implies x = 3(4p-1)+p=13p-3$. You can check that:  $32x - 8 = 32(13p-3)-8=13\cdot 32p - 104= 13(32p-8)$ which is divisible by $13$. I can do the other ones but leave it for you to apply my method to discover the answers !

$b)$  $39x - 65 = 169k \implies 3x - 5 = 13k\implies 3x = 13k + 5\implies x = 4k + \dfrac{k+5}{3}\implies k+5 = 3p \implies k = 3p-5\implies x = 4(3p-5)+p = 13p - 20$. You can check that these values of $x$ does the job as $3x - 5 = 3(13p-20) - 5 = 39p - 65 = 13(3p-5)$ which is divisible by $13$.

$c)$ Try it yourself ! I will get to it in a hour.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, I seem to have gotten a little confused when you introduced the n and then the p. What exactly do those variables represent? And also, what was the value of x you got? I apologize for any inconvenience. Thank you!

Comment: They are just integers . The "idea" is that if $3\mid x$ then I can write $x = 3p$ for example. So $p$ is just an integer.

Comment: Oh I see. So instead of writing a particular number, I should write x = 13p - 3 instead because their are many possible answers? Thank you!

Comment: True. that's the point. You transfer a modulo equation to a standard equation which is easier to deal with.

Comment: Sorry to be bothering you about this question again, but it seems like I am supposed to give the answer as a proper numerical integer. In other words, I just have to give one of the possibilities. Is there any way to derive a proper integer from the equations you have given? As is seems like p is just a carry on from k which is just a carry on from x. Also, to do part c, do I have to factorize the equation as it seems like it is harder to work with with two x's? Once again, my apologies. I would be grateful for your input.